# Need help understanding how a transistor works in this circuit

Tags: transistors

[image]

The circuit diagram I've attached has the direction of current flow represented by red arrows. It's the solution given for the 2006 Pennsylvania State Circuit lab competition for Science Olympiad from here: https://scioly.org/wiki/index.php/Test_Exchange_Archive#Circuit_Lab

I can't wrap my head around why Q1 has current going through it, but Q2 doesn't. It seems like current going down through R3 should engage the base of Q2 and current should flow down through the LEDs and through Q2...

Please help, so confused!

Comment: Would it be due to the resistance of C-E  for Q1 is much lower than B-E for Q2...

Comment: All the battery symbols are upside down. The large plate is positive. The circuit won't work. If the batteries were the right way up we'd need to know the resistor values to determine if the transistors are on or not.

Comment: This is supposed to be a circuit for a solar path light and the two batteries on the right are being charged. I forgot to mention that the one on the far left is a solar panel.

Comment: @Transistor The batteries have "+" and "-" indications, so I think it's safe to assume that the boss messed up and got them backwards.  When the teacher states the problem wrong, if you want a grade, you solve to the teacher's intent.

Comment: @SolarMike thats what i was kinda thinking too

Comment: Q1 is probably turned on hard enough that it is in saturation. This would pull the base of Q2 low enough that it wouldn't be able to turn on.  (And if Q2 did turn on hard, you'd almost certainly get excess current in the LEDs, because there's no current-limit resistors).

Comment: @TimWescott The battery plate schematic always seemed backwards to me. The shell of primary batteries is usually the negative so you'd think it ought to be the bigger one.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany me, too.  I'm sure it made sense in the 1750's or whenever the convention was established.  That's a schematic drawing of a Volta Pile there, kid!

Comment: @SpehroPefhany and that was when they guessed the direction of electrons traveling wrong... So sort of "correct" in a way... Does make the idea of a stack of plates with the top plate being positive...

Comment: slight sidenote: does anyone know why R2 is there? is it so that not too much current goes to the base of Q1?

Comment: @SolarMike Wiki's rendering of Alessandro Volta's [pile](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/06/Voltaic_pile.svg/1920px-Voltaic_pile.svg.png) and Volta's [original paper](http://electrochem.cwru.edu/estir/hist/hist-01-Volta-1.pdf) (which is in French) appears to show the disks (silver and zinc, I think) of identical diameter bonded together with electrolyte between them.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany the image shows Zinc and Copper - labelled clearly, but the paper is not available for some reason...

Comment: @SolarMike Sorry, I was referring to Volta's paper. The Wiki article mentions Zinc and Copper *or* Zinc and Silver. Volta's ca. 1800 paper has the [plates marked A and Z](https://i.imgur.com/iNFtvQt.png), presumably for Ag/Zn.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany still can't get to the paper... but Argentum is silver - I know that...

Comment: @SolarMike [Try again](https://web.archive.org/web/20130627232303/http://electrochem.cwru.edu/estir/hist/hist-01-Volta-1.pdf) with the paper.. it's from the wayback machine so the original link is scuppered.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany tried on 2 different machines - always « server stopped responding » anyway I made a "pile" when I was stiil at school - my Mum was not happy as I had used the lemon she needed....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the + and - of the batteries are correct and not the polarity shown by the battery symbols (the long line is the +, short line is -) and also assuming that the battery voltages are such that D1 isn't destroyed then:

It depends on the values of R1, R2 and R3 what mode of operation Q1 will be in.

If Q1 operates in **active mode** then it will have a large enough Vce to enable some current (coming from R3) to flow into the base of Q2. As the LEDs are indicted as not lighting up, we can assume that this is **not** the case.

If Q1 operates in **saturation mode** then Vce will be much smaller, typically less then 0.4 V which will prevent any current to flow into the base of Q2. For a current to flow into the base of Q2 there needs to be more than about 0.6 V across the base-emitter of Q2.

This isn't a well designed circuit. If Q2 would conduct then it also determined the current through the LEDs which (depending on Q1 and resistors) could be high enough for the LEDs to conduct too much current. There should have been resistors in series with the LEDs.

Comment: The batteries on the right are pairs of NiCd (\$1.2\:\text{V}\$ each.) (Per the contest question.) So, charged, they are at about \$2.4\:\text{V}\$. Given the \$V_\text{CE}\$ of \$Q_2\$ of a few tenths of a volt, it's likely it "worked okay" at night without too much fear of burning them out. The main problem I'd worry about is one of the two LEDs hogging most of the current with the other one being noticeably dimmer.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that the battery symbols appear to be drawn incorrectly, let's assume that Q1 is sufficiently biased so that it is fully saturated. If so, Vce of Q1 will be close to zero and so the input voltage to Q2 will be lower than the minimum voltage (typically about 0.6 to 0.7V) for Q2 to begin conducting. In other words, Q2 will be in cutoff and no current will flow through the two LEDs (shown as diodes).